# best practice for using an infinite while loop to process client/server data

Tags: c#, while-loop

I'm working on a client - server application. And I have an infinite while loop to check if the client (or server) has sent data.

```
while (true)
{
    // do things
}
```

But what is the best practice with this? With the above code, when the server accepts an client, the CPU of the system jumps to 100%.

If I put `Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)` at the end of the loop, CPU usages is better, but I wonder whether this is the best way, or whether it should be different.

(I am able to get the data asynchronously, I know--but my question isn't that, it's about the best practice for the while loop, so that the application does not completely consume the CPU)

Comment: well IMO the best practice here would be to use async reads (or if you don't want to, a *smaller* sleep - like 10ms)

Comment: just call a blocking read method and let the OS figure what to do with the CPU

Comment: This is definitely best practice for infinite `while` loop (which is expected to take 100% CPU in most cases). If your question about networking practices - async code is better approach.

Comment: Duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/q/1237996/395718

Comment: This case is only for the while loop. not about the networkstream. 
@Dialecticus where are you seeing the duplicate??? Next the one who give me the -1 could he explain why giving the downvote???

Comment: @Cageman I am not sure that removing `NetworkStream` related stuff was a good idea. At least it shows what you are working with, while(no pun intended) the `while` loop with empty `try-catch` seems only marginally related to your client-server problem and gives no indication of the technologies you use. In any case as Alexei has already pointed an [async networking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28008978/asynchronous-network-programming-with-async-await) is the right way to operate with network IO.

Comment: adding thread.sleep is bad practice. I don't get why people are relying on it. you need to execute this on a background thread so the main thread is not hijacked, hence your 100% CPU usage. Furthermore you should be using async/await as best practice and async development and was designed for things like this.

Comment: Now that you removed the code in the loop the question is not duplicate, but too broad. Is provided link not helpful for your case?

Comment: @Ahmedilyas your sysop might be a bit upset if a simple listening program/service is using up a complete core of his machine though ... just saying ;)

Comment: @Dialecticus. no, the question is about the while loop, not about the way to get the data (in your answer async)

Comment: @Cageman in this case the only answer is that in the general case you *should* **not** use a `while (true) {...}` at all

Answer (score 4):

> I wonder whether this is the best way

No.

An infinite loop without an escape mechanism (`break`, `yield return`), is (almost) never a good idea.

> or that it should be different

Yes.

You are doing a "busy waiting" loop, waiting for a client to send data. So your loop should be I/O bound, not CPU bound by repeatedly polling. This was already mentioned several times in the comments.

But lets suppose for the sake of argument that

- your code is actually CPU bound,
- you **periodically** need to "poll" for some condition in order to do something,
- you cannot "wait" for or "await" that condition using standard synchronization or signalling primitives (like a blocking queue, event, semaphore, ...).

Then there are at least two parts any solution needs to take care of:

1. A stop condition for your loop.
2. Only consuming CPU and occupying a thread when you actually need to.

**Stop condition**

One way of doing this is to use a `CancellationToken` that is connected to a `CancellationTokenSource` to allow a clean way of stopping.

```
while (!cancelToken.IsCancellationRequested)
{
    // Do stuff

    // Note: this still does not solve the issue of eating CPU resources.

    // If you were not polling periodically but waiting for a condition,
    // you could now do:
    try
    {
        var someResult = await MyCancelableAsyncOperation(..., cancelToken);
        // do stuff with this result.
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    {
        break; // done
    }
}
```

**Periodically polling**

Use a cancellable timer if you need to do things periodically.
See an example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30225642/2573395

Note that this example illustrates the basic idea. It could be modified to:

- Use a different timer than the `System.Timers.Timer`
- Adjust the timer interval dynamically if needed.

Comment: excellent answer and pretty much where I was aiming at in my comments under the OP :)

Comment: @Alex thanks, I think this was exactly what I looking for, upvoted your answer but not set to answered. Tonight I will do some research on the answer given.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever heard of `BackgroundWorker` Component?
It would be useful for your case.